# Trading Interview Question (Bullish, Bearish)?

Tags: trading, soft-question

I recently had a trading interview, and they asked this question. However, I had no idea how to answer it, and I was wondering if you could help me undersatnd it.

> Say you have a set of returns applied to an asset value, such as: {5%, -5%, 10%, -10%, 15%, -15%}. What sequence of returns would maximize the final asset value?

I wasn't sure, because wouldn't you end up with the same amount at the end? aka gaining 5% and losing 5% would put you less than you began with, how would you go about this?

Comment: did you get the job?

Comment: when you say combination of returns do you mean permutation of returns?

Comment: It seems like a strange question: Are these expected values only? Are these deterministic or stochastic? Are these returns on different assets or the same asset?
If they are deterministic, why would you *ever* choose anything else except 10%? If they are expected values, what is their variance? Given their mean and variance, what is the utility function? Are you risk neutral/risk averse?

Comment: The first question was look for the answer provided by @amsh, there was probably a follow-up question asking if the price would be exactly the same as the initial price.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter since multiplication is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) (in $\mathbb{R}$); you will always end up losing the same.

Comment: For convenience, the meaning of "multiplication is commutative (in $\mathbb{R}$)" is that multiplication of real numbers can be re-ordered without changing the result. Notice that this is not the case for matrices for example.

Answer (score 3):

While amsh's answer definitely gives you what you need for interview purposes, for any visual learners like me, here's what running through all possible paths ends up looking like.

[image]

Another thing I might consider bringing up in an interview context would be the intuitive reasoning behind why it works out this way. In other words, just explaining that a 15% loss on \$130 has a larger gross impact than a 15% gain on \$70. Then you can talk about geometric returns, high water marks, etc. to demonstrate that you understand the financial/business relevance of what's going on mathematically.

--

For reference, the R code I threw together to make the graph above:

```
r = c(5, -5, 10, -10, 15, -15) * 0.01
x0 = 100

k = length(r)
n = factorial(k)
r = sort(r)
permList = combinat::permn(r)
results = matrix(NA, n, k+1)
results[,1] = x0
if (n != length(permList)) stop("factorial(length(r)) != length([permutations])")
for (i in 1:n)
    for (j in 2:(k+1))
        results[i,j] = results[i,j-1] + results[i,j-1]*permList[[i]][j-1]

if (!("Euclid" %in% names(windowsFonts())))
    windowsFonts(Euclid=windowsFont("Euclid"))
par(family="Euclid", mar=c(2.5,2.5,0.5,0.5), mgp=c(1.5,0.5,0), cex=0.75)
matplot(t(results), pch=19, type='o', col=rgb(1:n/n,0,n:1/n,n/(k*n)), xlab='', ylab='', main='')
grid(lty=1, col=rgb(0,0,0,0.2))
abline(h=x0, lty=2)
title(xlab=expression(t), ylab=expression(X[t]), font=3)
```